# Functions: Returning strings and tuples of lists?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

Working these functions and I'm having trouble returning the lists of strings to tuples and indexes. First one I'm trying to return every first occurrence of the letter strings with its index location, but so far I'm only able to return a single string with its index, how can I make it so it iterates through each list and chooses the earliest occurrence of the string?

```
area3 = [['.', '.', '.', 'a'], 
         ['.', 'B', '.', 'a'], 
         ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
         ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', 'x', '.', '.']]
def zone_lists(area):
    for row in area:
        for letter in row:
            if ('A' <= letter <= 'Z' or 'a' <= letter <= 'z'): 
                return letter, area.index(row), row.index(letter)
zone_lists(area3) # Should return [('a', 0, 3), ('B', 1, 0), ('Y', 3, 1), ('x', 5, 1)]
```

In this function, it should return the later string value of 'e', but I'm getting a value error. I'm not sure if the recursive call is correct, is there a way call it without using built in functions like enumerate?

```
def last_list_val(value,area):
    for row in area:
        for letter in row:
            if value == letter:
                return area.index(row[0:-1]), row.index(letter[0:-1]) #Backward call?
last_list_val('Y',area3) #Should return (3,3)
```

Comment: So only the first letter matters? i.e., `['.', 'B', '.', 'a']` the `'a'` is ignored?

Comment: Yes, for the first function yes. In the 2nd function, it should pick the 'Y' that's farthest to the bottom which is (3,3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function:

```
area3 = [['.', '.', '.', 'a'], 
         ['.', 'B', '.', 'a'], 
         ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
         ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', 'x', '.', '.']]
def zone_lists(area):
    result = []
    for i, row in enumerate(area):
        for j, letter in enumerate(row):
            if letter.isalpha():
                result.append((letter, i, j))
                break  # remove this line if you want to have both 'B' and 'a' from row 1
    return result

zone_lists(area3) # Should return [('a', 0, 3), ('B', 1, 0), ('Y', 3, 1), ('x', 5, 1)]
```

The second:

```
def last_list_val(value, area):
    for i in range(len(area) - 1, -1, -1):
        row = area[i]
        for j in range(len(row) - 1, -1, -1):
            letter = row[j]
            if value == letter:
                return i, j
```

I used `enumerate` here in the first function. But if you don't like it (or some reason can not use it), you can always use the old fashion `for i in range(len(area)):` to get the indice and use `area[i]` to get the corresponding values, like I did in the second function (slightly different because I did them reversely).

Comment: Would the area[i] go at the end of the for loop or before?

Comment: @HalLawrence Just use enumerate. `area[i]` would go anywhere `row` goes, and `row[j]` would go anywhere `letter` goes, but it is so much more readable with enumerate, as you see.

Comment: Is there an alternative to the .isalpha? I'm trying to use as least built in functions as possible.

Comment: You can still use the `'A' <= letter <= 'Z' or 'a' <= letter <= 'z'`.

Answer (score 1):

This makes a nice generator.

Consider:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def zone_list(area):
    for i, sl in enumerate(area):
        t=next(((j,e) for j,e in enumerate(sl) if e in ascii_letters), None)
        if t: 
            yield (t[1], i, t[0])
```

Then test that:

```
>>> list(zone_list(area3))
[('a', 0, 3), ('B', 1, 1), ('Y', 3, 1), ('x', 5, 1)]
```

The second function then becomes:

```
def last_list_val(value,area):
    for i, sl in enumerate(area):
        seq=[(j,e) for j,e in enumerate(sl) if e==value]            
        if len(seq)>1:
            yield (i, seq[-1][0])
```

And then:

```
>>> list(last_list_val('Y', area3))
[(3, 3)]
```